# Rails bundler change branch of gem depending on environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

I am trying to use a different branch in my Gemfile.rb depending on the Rails environment. Is this possible?

I have tried the following, but the branch is always branch_B regardless of environment:

```
branch = 'branch_A'
group :production do
  branch = 'branch_B'
end
gem 'gem_name', git:'git_url', branch: branch
```

Comment: Where are you getting the branch from ? Are you going to  `hard code` it in the future ?

Comment: The branch names are hard-coded, I want the branch to be branch_B in production and branch_A in other environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps

```
def branch
    if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "production"
        @branch = 'branch_B'
        puts "I'm in production"
    else
        @branch = 'branch_A'
        puts "I'm in development"
    end
end

gem 'sqlite3', branch: branch
```

In terminal, you'll have to run

`RAILS_ENV=development bundle`

Comment: Thanks, i ended up doing something similar in the Gemfile. I used the environment variable as you suggested to set the branch accordingly.